# Video is playing without audio (but not muted) in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, video

I have the video tag as follows,

```
 <div class="feature-image">
     <video width="550" height="300" controls>
           <source src="/static/resources/vid/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           <source src="/static/resources/vid/my_video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                        {{'LBL_VIDEO_ERROR_MESSAGE' | translate }}
     </video>
  </div>
```

[image]
This is working fine in local but not in my test server.Do I need to do any thing in specific.

Comment: your browser tab might be muted

Comment: but the other videos are getting played

Comment: When video plays try to click on the tab icon

Comment: what if you play the video on a media player? does it have sound?

Comment: yes it has sounds

Comment: @MarkMinerov where I can find the tab icon button

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AVN3Nr0 here it is

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `[muted]` property to `false` value:

```
<video  [muted]="false">
    <source src="/static/resources/vid/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/static/resources/vid/my_video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                    {{'LBL_VIDEO_ERROR_MESSAGE' | translate }}
</video>
```